# How do I remove the first line from a FASTA format file during input?

Tags: perl, bioinformatics, fasta

I want to remove the first line during input from a FASTA file, so that my program takes only the amino acid sequence as input.

The first line of a FASTA file starts with `>` and it contains the 'accession number' of the sequence and the source of it. E.g.:

```
>MCHU - Calmodulin - Human, rabbit, bovine, rat, and chicken    
ADQLTEEQIAEFKEAFSLFDKDGDGTITTKELGTVMRSLGQNPTEAELQDMINEVDADGNGTID 
FPEFLTMMARKMKDTDSEEEIREAFRVFDKDGNGYISAAELRHVMTNLGEKLTDEEVDEMIREA 
DIDGDGQVNYEEFVQMMTAK*
```

Comment: Can you give an example and/or some code you've tried?

Comment: First line starts with ">" and it contains 'accession number' of the sequence and source of it. Eg.  


>MCHU - Calmodulin - Human, rabbit, bovine, rat, and chicken
   ADQLTEEQIAEFKEAFSLFDKDGDGTITTKELGTVMRSLGQNPTEAELQDMINEVDADGNGTID
   FPEFLTMMARKMKDTDSEEEIREAFRVFDKDGNGYISAAELRHVMTNLGEKLTDEEVDEMIREA
   DIDGDGQVNYEEFVQMMTAK*

Comment: Edited that into your question. And [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: You could also use BioPerl  [Retrieving a sequence from a file](http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/HOWTO:Beginners#Retrieving_a_sequence_from_a_file)

Comment: I fully agree with Chris Charley's suggestion to [`use Bio::Perl;`](http://search.cpan.org/~cjfields/BioPerl-1.6.901/Bio/Perl.pm)--especially if your (academic) focus is bioinformatics.  It and its ilk have all the tools you need to work with FASTA files, and you'll greatly benefit in the long run from knowing how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip lines starting with `>`:

```
while(<>) {
    next if /^>/;
    # ...
}
```

or, use `$.` (current input line number) to skip the first one:

```
while(<>) {
    next if $. < 2;
    # ...
}
```